# compare files in two directory and write delta

Tags: linux, search, compare, diff, rsync

**I can't find difference between two directories: what updated, and what deleted.
After that I need save new files into archive and a list of deleted files.**

After that I need with copy of first directory + delta go to new directory and recreate there directory 2.

**All this must be fast =)**

I tried rsync

```
time rsync -rv --dry-run --delete ./10 ./130
sent 775081 bytes  received 105052 bytes  352053.20 bytes/sec
total size is 838724381  speedup is 952.95 (DRY RUN)
real    0m1.270s
user    0m0.300s
sys     0m0.484s
```

But I don't see deleted files

## rsync --version

rsync  version 3.0.9  protocol version 30
Copyright (C) 1996-2011 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/

Maybe I don't understand someting:

```
root@RDE-1.3:/home.local/diff# rm -rf a/
root@RDE-1.3:/home.local/diff# rm -rf b
root@RDE-1.3:/home.local/diff# mkdir a b
root@RDE-1.3:/home.local/diff# touch b/ssdf
root@RDE-1.3:/home.local/diff# touch a/c
root@RDE-1.3:/home.local/diff# rsync --dry-run -i  --delete-delay  --stats -a  a b |grep "deleting"
root@RDE-1.3:/home.local/diff# rsync --dry-run -i  --delete-delay  --stats -a  a b
cd+++++++++ a/
>f+++++++++ a/c

Number of files: 2
Number of files transferred: 1
```

I created in directory files which don't exists in another but they wouldn't delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rsync` may not necessarily be faster. What you are observing is Linux filesystem caching:

```
$ time find /usr/share > /dev/null
real    0m6.779s
user    0m0.082s
sys 0m0.199s

$ time find /usr/share > /dev/null
real    0m0.109s
user    0m0.043s
sys 0m0.064s
```

Notice how the second search is instantaneous.

Comment: Not run before: time rsync --dry-run -i  --delete-delay  --stats -a  ./131 ./230  

     real    0m1.487s     
     user    0m0.304s  
     sys     0m0.568s

Comment: @ValeriySolovyov Try to format your comment to make it readable.

Comment: I test rsync and diff. Rsync was faster, but it's not important.     I didn't find answer.